# Django 1.3 new "localize" tag/filter doesn't work?

Tags: django, templates

I've noticed that Django 1.3 introduced the new "localize" tag/filter.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/

It says:

> To activate or deactivate localization
>   for a template block, use:
>
> ```
> {% localize on %}
>     {{ value }}
> {% endlocalize %}
>
> {% localize off %}
>     {{ value }}
> {% endlocalize %}
> ```

However I always got the error message:

> Invalid block tag: 'localize'

Looks like the "localize" filter doesn't work as well. Can anybody help me? Or can anybody else confirm if this is a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Have you loaded the localization template tags with:

```
{% load l10n %}
```

before using "localize" template tag?

Comment: You are right, now it works! BTW, what's the difference between {% load l10n %} and {% load i18n %}? I tried both and seems like they do the same thing.